# Search bar doesn't work on different page tabs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tabs, webbrowser-control

I have a search bar and tabcontrol and a web broswer, each time a tab is opened a web browser appears but when I type in the search box it only appears to work in the first page tab

Here is my tab control code:

```
var browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
browser.Url = new Uri(@"http://www.google.com");
myTabPage.Controls.Add(browser);
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
```

and my search bar code:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com/search?q=" + searchField.Text);
```

My code so far doesnt seem to be working,

```
private void searchTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string browserURL = "";
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (yahoosearch.Checked == true)
        {
            browserURL = "www.search.yahoo.com/search?q=" + searchTextBox.Text;
        }
        else if (bingsearch.Checked == true)
        {
            browserURL = "www.bing.com/search?q=" + searchTextBox.Text;
        }
        else if (googlesearch.Checked == true)
        {
            browserURL = "www.google.com/search?q=" + searchTextBox.Text;
        }
    }

    foreach (var c in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
    {
        if (c is WebBrowser)
        {
            ((WebBrowser)c).Navigate(searchTextBox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Could it be that my web browser is called `webBrowser1`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've created the first tab in the designer and you call the search bar code for `webBrowser1`. But on other paged your webbroser is `var browser`, so you should call navigate  on it:

```
foreach (var c in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
{
    if (c is WebBrowser)
    {
        ((WebBrowser)c).Navigate(browserURL);
    }
}
```

Comment: How easy is it to add the url to the actaul tab been looking for examples and tutorials but all very complex

Comment: @user1934845 you are already doing that by appending it's content to google search. see my edit

Comment: I have used this with the code I already have for the keydown searchbox but none of it seems to work not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @user1934845 I also do not know what you are doing wrong, because I don't see what you are doing

Comment: Do I add the foreach code on the code when I have double clicked the search box or do I put it in my searchboxkeydown event? I have updated my code in the question which includes what you wrote but it doesnt work.

Comment: @user1934845 you are welcome, please mark my answer as solution :)